# Un mot qui signifie « ce qui dérange constamment » ou « ce qui rend fou constamment ou toujours »

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, poésie

**Contexte:**

Je cherche un mot pour signifier quelque chose qui dérange ou rend fou... constamment.  Je peux penser seulement aux exemples de la littérature anglaise.  Je pense à [*The Raven*](http://www.heise.de/ix/raven/Literature/Lore/TheRaven.html) d'Edgar Allan Poe et [*The Rime of the Ancient Mariner*](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/173253) (L'expression anglaise "The albatross around my neck") de Samuel Taylor Coleridge.

**Question:**

**Je cherche un mot, une expression, ou une idiome qui signifie bien l'idée de quelque chose qui dérange constamment.  Un mot poétique, qui n'est pas familier.**

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr de voir ce que tu cherches à qualifier : un évènement répétée ou prolongée qui dérange (un voisin bruyant, par exemple, ou le bruit d’un robinet qui fuit), un évènement passé qui pèse sur ta conscience (pourquoi diable ai-je tué cet albatros ?), le passé qui te hante (les souvenirs de Lénore) ?

Comment: @Édouard J'ai changé la question.  Elle est maintenant scindée.  Cette question est au sujet du mot que je cherches.  Je veux aussi clarifier... C'est un événement répétée ou prolongée qui dérange, mais pas celle qui est seulement ennuyeuse ou fatigante... plutôt celle qui rend fou (sombrer dans la démence).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Horripilant](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/horripilant) et [ce site](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/fr/index_tr.html) propose aussi : crispant, exaspérant, excédant, agaçant, importun, irritant, suffocant, vexant, énervant (dans cette liste, exaspérant me semble aussi être un bon choix) en permettant de visualiser ces mots groupés suivant leur proximité sémantique.

Comment: J'ai m.a.j. la question.  Peut-être que vous voulez la relire au cas où il y a besoin de changer la réponse.

Comment: Pour compléter cette excellente liste et couvrir "rend fou", j'ajouterai "aliénant".

Comment: @rangzen, à mon avis, ce terme a acquis beaucoup trop de conations politiques, sociologiques et psychologiques pour être utilisé comme adjectif sans risquer de les voir surgir.  (L'utilisation comme participe présent avec des complément peu rendre le sens clair).

Answer (score 4):

Je propose quand même [aliénant](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/ali%C3%A9nant) qui me semble être le seul qui possède ce coté « fou » :-).

Answer (score 1):

Dans un contexte familier, extraits du [dictionnaire de la langue française](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/fou/). :

> C'est à rendre *dingue,  barjot,  braque, cinglé,  dingo, dingue, fada,
>   farfelu, fêlé, givré, déglingué*.

Pour rester dans l'univers des poèmes cités, une expression poétique des symptômes *déraisonnables, d'aliénation, déments, déséquilibrés, névrosés* (un mot seul ne peut suffire à ouvrir le champ/chant poétique):

- Son âme affolée perdait le sens commun.
- Les ténèbres qu'il vécu lui firent perdre l'esprit.
- Tétanisé d'horreur, prostré il finit par déambuler, hagard.
- La raison abandonne l'amour séparé par la mort.

Quatre parmi les mille autres raisons de *perdre la tête*.

Answer (score 1):

Hors de la poésie, il y a *harcèlement*.

Answer (score 1):

Un mot qui sort du commun pour exprimer la folie ("fou") : *azimuté*.